# How to view JSON response generated by GET method in HP Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing

how to view JSON response which is generated by GET method and while after executing the script.

Load runner version 12.5.

Protocol: Web HTTP/HTML.

Request: GET

Any help/guidence appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Correlate for value.  Use a lr_message() variant to output it to your preferred destination.